# HiveQLWhere error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, python, hive, hadoop2

**HiveQLWhere.java:21: error:** cannot find symbol

```
  Resultset res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tls");
```

**symbol:**   `class Resultset`

**location:** `class HiveQLWhere`

I am new to java and have help me to solve this error in **Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to comment because I don't have enough reputation.  You might want to add a bit more to your question so others can help.

Here is a resource that may help

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hiveql_select_where.htm

My guess would be to try adding a semicolon in the Select query.

```
Resultset res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tls;");
```

Comment: No problem! I hope everything is all fixed :)